# Difficulty with datatool

Tags: datatool

I want to use the command `\DTLstoreinitials` from package `\usepackage{datatool}` in the following way :

```
\newcommand{\extractInitials}[1]{%
\DTLstoreinitials{#1}{\userInitials}%
\DTLsubstituteall{\userInitials}{.}{}%remove points between the initials
\DTLsubstituteall{\userInitials}{ }{}%remove spaces
\userInitials%
}
```

If I call the command directly, it works :

```
\extractInitials{My Name}
```

gives `MN`. But if I use an auxiliary command: `\newcommand{\nom}{My Name}` and try to call

```
\extractInitials{\nom}
```

then the compilation fails with error

```
! Paragraph ended before \@dtl@initials was complete.
```

How can I fix this?

---

Here is a minimal example 1 :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{trackchanges}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\extractInitials}[1]{%
%\expandafter\DTLstoreinitials\expandafter{#1}{\userInitials}%
\DTLstoreinitials{#1}{\userInitials}%
\DTLsubstituteall{\userInitials}{.}{}%remove points 
\DTLsubstituteall{\userInitials}{ }{}%remove spaces
}
\begin{document}
\extractInitials{AAA BBB}\addeditor{\userInitials}
\extractInitials{CCC DDD}\addeditor{\userInitials}
----------- \\% to see the result of the addeditor commands
\makeatletter
\TC@editorOne\\
\TC@editorTwo\\
\TC@editorThree\\
\makeatother
-----------
\end{document}
```

The output is 
    CD
    n/n
    n/n
To compare : example 2

```
\addeditor{AB}
\addeditor{CD}
----------- \\% to see the result of the addeditor commands
\makeatletter
\TC@editorOne\\
\TC@editorTwo\\
\TC@editorThree\\
\makeatother
-----------
```

The output is 
    AB
    CD
    n/n

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post. I've edited your post accordingly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Note that you can edit your posts to add more information. Answer posts are for solutions to the question.

Comment: I've added note 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two choices.

### First

```
\newcommand{\extractInitials}[1]{%
  \expandafter\DTLstoreinitials\expandafter{#1}{\userInitials}%
\DTLsubstituteall{\userInitials}{.}{}%remove points between the initials
\DTLsubstituteall{\userInitials}{ }{}%remove spaces
\userInitials
}
```

This can be used if `\nom` expands immediately to the name and no more processing is needed.

The trick is to access at `#1` before processing by `\DTLstoreinitials` begins. The first `\expandafter` acts on the second, which in turn expands the first token after the brace: in your case it can be `\nom`; if you give directly a name nothing happens (but see the second note).

### Second

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extractInitials}[1]{%
  \begingroup\protected@edef\x{%
    \endgroup\noexpand\DTLstoreinitials{#1}{\noexpand\userInitials}}\x%
\DTLsubstituteall{\userInitials}{.}{}%remove points between the initials
\DTLsubstituteall{\userInitials}{ }{}%remove spaces
\userInitials
}
\makeatother
```

This is to be preferred if the contents of `\nom` is more complicated (say `\nom` becomes `\Prenom\space\Nom`. Here we expand until the bottom, but "robusted" macros such as those for accented letters remain untouched.

### Note 1

Using `\edef` in this context directly is bound to break if the argument of `\extractInitials` contains accented characters (even when a control sequence is used).

### Note 2

In both cases, results are unpredictable if the first initial is an accented letter. Put it as `{É}lie Cartan` to get a correct result. However, none of the method works reliably in this case if the input encoding is UTF-8 (for limitations of `datatool`). Write *always* a first accented initial in braces.

### Note 3

In case this macro must be fed to another command, the result will depend on what this macro does. For example it will work with `\textbf{\extractInitials{My Name}}`, since `\textbf` wants only to print its argument. In other cases a different approach must be taken; for example, in your test document one has to take an indirect path:

```
\newcommand{\extractInitials}[1]{%
  \expandafter\DTLstoreinitials\expandafter{#1}{\userInitials}%
\DTLsubstituteall{\userInitials}{.}{}%remove points between the initials
\DTLsubstituteall{\userInitials}{ }{}%remove spaces
}
\newcommand{\myaddeditor}[1]{%
  \extractInitials{#1}\expandafter\addeditor\expandafter{\userInitials}}
```

and then say `\myaddeditor{AAA BBB}`

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use the first one, since `\nom` expands immediately to the name in my case, and i have accented letter.
It works, but i don't quite understand the trick :). Could you explain it to me ? I understand the first `\expandafter`, it insure that the argumen #1 will be first expanded. But why to "expand" \userItinials ? I thought this is a temporary command where DTLstoreinitials stores the result of the string operation...

Comment: Another problem i'm facing : i'm using the result of `\extractInitials` in some other command `\somecommand{\extractInitials{My Name}}` but it fails. This command is one from a package, and i don't know exactly how it is defined. But is there a way to make `\extractInitials` completely expand, before we give it as an argument to `\somecommand`, so that the compilation doesnt fails, even if we don't know how `\somecommand` is build ?

Comment: @nicolasroy Please add to the question a minimal example; you should register on the site (the moderators can then merge other questions you submitted as an unregistered user).

Comment: Well, my question was precisely, how can i make the command `\extractInitials` sufficiently robust, so that i can use it inside any command in the future... But ok, for the moment, i want to be able to use: 
`\addeditor{\extractInitials{My Name}}` where `\addeditor` is a command from the package trackchanges.

Comment: @nicolasroy If you cut the last `\userInitials` from the main macro and say `\extractInitials{My Name}\addeditor{\userInitials}` it might work (maybe with a couple of `\expandafter`s).

Comment: I'm really confused. With your last proposition, it compiles, but, if i use twice these commands : 
    `\extractInitials{AAA BBB}\addeditor{\userInitials}
%
    \extractInitials{CCC DDD}\addeditor{\userInitials}` then it remembers somehow only the last one... To understand what i mean, one should of course use the command addeditor. But in particular, if i type explicitly `\adduser{AB} \adduser{CD}` then it does what it should do. But with \userInitials it does the job only for the last line. I don't know if i am clear...

Comment: @nicolasroy Why don't you try giving a minimal example?